# Node.js, express.js, Windows Server and EADDRINUSE

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows-server

I've got a node.js express.js server setup. It's really simple, just serves up a static html page and listens on port 17500:

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 17500;

const index = path.join(__dirname, 'index.html');

console.log('Current NodeJs Version:', process.version);
console.log('Index.html:', index);

app.use((req, res) => res.sendFile(index));

app.listen(port, function (err) {
  if (err){
    console.error(err.message);
    process.exit();
  }else{
    console.log('Listening on port', port);
  }
});
```

It was working fine until it was force closed. Now whenever I try and run it it says `Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::17500`. Node is not running and netstat -an does not show any connections on 17500. Stranger still, if I change the port to one I *know* is not in use (21000, e.g.) it says `Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::21000`.

Anyone have any idea what is wrong? Bear in mind, I *must not* restart the server!

Comment: I have found that other ghost node instances are running in the background that are taking that port, as if they didn't quite shutdown properly!

Comment: How can I find these, tasklist/Get-Process/taskmgr.exe show nothing related to node or my application :(!

Comment: Yeah I do `ctrl + shift + esc` and use task manager

Comment: There's no references to node there, that's the trouble.. hmm!

Comment: closes the process that has been left alive