# Service Fabric node.js guest application express.js server EADDRINUSE

Tags: node.js, express, azure-service-fabric

Not sure if this is a service fabric issue, or issue with node.js.

Basically [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42163684/node-js-express-js-windows-server-and-eaddrinuse) is my problem. I deploy the node.js application, it works fine. I redeploy the node application it fails to work, with the server returning `EADDRINUSE`. When I run `netstat -an` the port isn't in use. It's as if node is still running somewhere, some how, but not appearing in tasklist etc..

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure, but I believe this is because the server I was using (express.js), or rather node, was not shutting down and closing existing connections causing windows to think the ports are still in use. At least, that's how it seems.

I can not find it "officially" documented, but from [this](https://disqus.com/home/discussion/thewindowsazureproductsite/deploy_an_existing_application_in_azure_service_fabric/) (quoted below) it reads SF sends SIGINT to the application to attempt to end it before killing it.

The following code appears to fix my issue:

```
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(17500);

if (process.platform === "win32") {
    var rl = require("readline").createInterface({
        input: process.stdin,
        output: process.stdout
    });

    rl.on("SIGINT", function () {
        process.emit("SIGINT");
    }
}

process.on("SIGINT", function() {
    server.close(function () {
        process.exit(0);
    });
});
```

For Linux nodes, I suppose you'd want to listen for "SIGTERM" as well.

I would like to know if there's any sort of remediation for this though, in the previously mentioned scenario the VMSS was completely unusable -- I could not deploy, nor run, a node web server. How does one restart the cluster without destroying it and recreating it? I now realise you can't just restart VMSS instances willy-nilly because service fabric completely breaks if you do that, apparently irrevocably

---

> Rajeet Nair [RajeetN@MSFT]
>
> Service Fabric also sends a Ctrl-C to service processes and waits for service to terminate. If the service doesn't terminate for 3 minutes, the process is killed.